# Bootstrap button dropdown hides into overflow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My dropdown button hides into a overflow div, see the image, before I click on the button.
[image]

Image below I clicked on the button
[image]

Look there, dropdown-content is into my 'overflowed' div, how I resolve that?
I'm using bootstrap 3.4.
I created my own dropdown menu already, but I get the same problem.

Comment: I want dropdown-content with overup of all elements

Comment: Can you show us your html so we can check if you're adding the correct classes?

Comment: @MarvelMoe is there, thanks for attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding overflow for all the elements in users class.

```
.users .user > * {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can remove it if not needed. or keep that and overwrite as

```
.users .user .control {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEVgYE)

Comment: https://codepen.io/thecodermarcelo/pen/KXoPNX  Now the dropdown content of the first of the list is under of the second of the list

Comment: take out the `z-index: 1;` from `.users .user > *` styles. here is the working codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWLzwp